# angular routing without webserver to load templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possibile in angular to load templates without web server,
I found one example here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/LXzaAWqWEus
but for me it is only printing templates paths not content for them.

Is there any working example for this?

Comment: why would you want to do this?  You can define the templates inline in most cases if you're simply trying to avoid having to setup a server environment I don't know why, it's trivial with lamp, wamp, mamp, or on linux with any package manager installing apache2 or some other web-server?

Comment: I need to make one app that will be shipped as is, without need of web server. Question is: is it possibile and how?

Comment: that's a valid reason I just get a bit annoyed with people who want to do it their way just because but don't really have a valid reason for doing things in a non-standard way.  Don't have an answer but seems a legitimate request.

Answer (score 1):

I'm ignoring the "no web server" part of the question. Here's an example on how you can put a template directly in a script tag and use it with a directive.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateTemplate.html">
     <div>
     I am the <span ng-transclude>{{templateAdjective}}</span> 
     template result.
     </div>
</script>

<div>
    <test>best</test>
    <test>optimal</test>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    app.directive('test', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'templateTemplate.html',    
            transclude: true,
            replace: true
        };
    });
</script>
</body>
```

[template in script tag jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FxGKH/1/)

Comment: It's worth noting that a `script` tag with a type of `text/ng-template` and an ID inserts the contents of the script into the [`$templateCache` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache), so you can use the service to access that data outside of `templateUrl` properties.